# Awesomium click event in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, click, awesomium

```
 For Each link As HtmlNode In doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div")
  if link.id="first album" then
           'this code needed'
  end if
 next
```

The above code finds me the button i need, but how do i click this button?

Answer (score 1):

```
dim xpath as string
xpath = ".//ul[@class='dropdown-menu action-dropdown']/li/a"
Dim nlink As JSObject =wc.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult([String].Format("document.evaluate(""{0}"", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue", xpath))
nlink.InvokeAsync("click")
```

tnx BrettJ

you can get xpath by google chrome
xpath plugin
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The code below is successful.

```
For Each link As HtmlNode In doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div")
    If link.id = "first album" Then
        xpath = link.xpath
        Dim nlink As JSObject = WebControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult([String].Format("document.evaluate(""{0}"", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue", xpath))
            nlink.InvokeAsync("click")
    End If
Next
```